# javascript disable textbox in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have these three fields in my jsp page.

```
    <td>
           <html:text property="my_dto.number1" </html:text>
   </td>
    <td>
           <html:text property="my_dto.number2" </html:text> 
    </td>

    <td>                                    
          <input type ="checkbox" id ='isTrue' /> 
    </td>
```

now i want if isTrue is checked the two text box will be disabled. how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fact: JSP runs at webserver, produces HTML/CSS/JS and sends it to webbrowser. JS runs at webbrowser and sees only the HTML DOM tree, not any line of Java/JSP. Rightclick page in webbrowser, choose *View Souce* and see yourself. Do you understand this? OK, then continue.

In the generated HTML source you should see some HTML `<input type="text">` elements in place of Struts' `<html:text>` components. I don't do Struts, but a bit decent MVC framework will assign those HTML elements an `id` as well. If not done or when the ID value is randomly generated, you'd like to set a fixed ID yourself. According the [TLD documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/text.html), you need to set the `styleId` attribute: `<html:text styleId="someFixedId">`.

Finally, write a JS function which get executed on click of the checkbox and modifies the `disabled` attribute of those text elements accordingly. Andy E has already given some hints. Here is how the JSP should basically look like:

```
<html:text property="my_dto.number1" styleId="number1" />
<html:text property="my_dto.number2" styleId="number2" /> 
<input type="checkbox" id="isTrue" onclick="disableNumbers(this)" /> 

<script>
    function disableNumbers(checkbox) {
        var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
        var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
        number1.disabled = number2.disabled = checkbox.checked;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think *onchange* would be more suitable, *onclick* won't fire if you focus the checkbox and press the spacebar key.  I can't remember if *onchange* fires before or after though, so a 0ms timeout might also be needed.

Comment: @Andy: it will :) [Test yourself](http://jsbin.com/erene3). Oh, there's one more disadvantage of onchange: it get only fired when checkbox loses focus.

Comment: huh, I couldn't find that documented anywhere...  You're right about the *change* event firing when focus is lost (but it's not true of all browsers and it's only the case when the keyboard is used).  I think you've proven the *click* event works better for this situation though, +1 :-)

Comment: @Andy: not only for this situation. Always use it whenever you want to hook on a change of checkbox / radio button. The `onchange` on those elements won't behave as you'd intuitively expect.